# Is this javasScript sorting function correct?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, html-lists

I'm a javaScript begginer. This function works and allows me to sorting list by ascendant and descendant by clicking in a button but I would like to know if it's properly written or maybe it can be simplified or written differently. Thanks in advance.

index.html

```
<p id="sort">Sort</p>
<ul>
  <li>Phosphorus</li>
  <li>Polonium</li>
  <li>Radium</li>
  <li>Fluorine</li>
  <li>Iron</li>
  <li>Hydrogen</li>
  <li>Germanium</li>
  <li>Mercury</li>
  <li>Actinium</li>
  <li>Barium</li>
  <li>Calcium</li>
  <li>Cadmium</li>
</ul>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
const sortButton = document.querySelector("#sort");
let counter = 0;


eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
   sortButton.addEventListener("click", sortList);
}

function sortList() {
   const elementsList = new Array();
   const elements = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
   for (const element of elements) {
       elementsList.push(element.textContent);
   }
   const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
   ul.innerHTML = "";

   if (counter % 2 === 0) {
       const orderedList = elementsList.sort();
       for (let i = 0; i < orderedList.length; i++) {
           const li = document.createElement("li");
           li.innerHTML = orderedList[i];
           ul.appendChild(li);
       }
       counter++;
   } else {
       const orderedList = elementsList.reverse();
       for (let i = 0; i < orderedList.length; i++) {
           const li = document.createElement("li");
           li.innerHTML = orderedList[i];
           ul.appendChild(li);
       }
       counter++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have to clear the innerHTML of the ul, nor even ever use innerHTML

element.appendChild will move existing elements - as below

```js
const sortButton = document.querySelector("#sort");
let counter = 0;
eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
   sortButton.addEventListener("click", sortList);
}

function sortList() {
   const elementsList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul li"));
   const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
   elementsList.sort(({textContent:a}, {textContent:b})=>(counter%2?-1:1)*a.localeCompare(b))
   .forEach(el => ul.appendChild(el));
   counter++;
}
```

```html
<p id="sort">Sort</p>
<ul>
  <li>Phosphorus</li>
  <li>Polonium</li>
  <li>Radium</li>
  <li>Fluorine</li>
  <li>Iron</li>
  <li>Hydrogen</li>
  <li>Germanium</li>
  <li>Mercury</li>
  <li>Actinium</li>
  <li>Barium</li>
  <li>Calcium</li>
  <li>Cadmium</li>
</ul>
```

In Es2015 (i.e. old school javascirpt) - this function looks like:

```
function sortList() {
  var elementsList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("ul li"));
  var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
  elementsList.sort(function (_ref, _ref2) {
    var a = _ref.textContent;
    var b = _ref2.textContent;
    return (counter % 2 ? -1 : 1) * a.localeCompare(b);
  }).forEach(function (el) {
    return ul.appendChild(el);
  });
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your function but i'm not sure what this two lines of code do:

elementsList.sort(({textContent:a}, {textContent:b})=>(counter%2?-1:1)*a.localeCompare(b))
   .forEach(el => ul.appendChild(el));

could you rewrite it without using arrow function?

Comment: @OscarVA - let me rewrite that in old javascript (this code is using ES6+ features)

Comment: Sorry to ask you again. I understand the whole function except this snippet (including the asterisk): "(counter% 2? -1: 1) *". All I know is that it is a ternary conditional

Comment: it negates the output to sort ascending/descending ... multiplying the result of `localeCompare` (which outputs -1, 0 or 1) by 1 or -1